# Presto failing to query hive table

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, emr, presto

On EMR I created a dataset in parquet using spark and storing it on S3.
I am currently able to create an external table and query it using hive but when I try to perform the same query using presto I obtain an error (the part referred changes at every run).

```
2016-11-13T13:11:15.165Z        ERROR   remote-task-callback-36 com.facebook.presto.execution.StageStateMachine Stage 20161113_131114_00004_yp8y5.1 failed
com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Error opening Hive split s3://my_bucket/my_table/part-r-00013-b17b4495-f407-49e0-9d15-41bb0b68c605.snappy.parquet (offset=1100508800, length=68781800): null
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetHiveRecordCursor.createParquetRecordReader(ParquetHiveRecordCursor.java:475)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetHiveRecordCursor.<init>(ParquetHiveRecordCursor.java:247)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetRecordCursorProvider.createHiveRecordCursor(ParquetRecordCursorProvider.java:96)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HivePageSourceProvider.getHiveRecordCursor(HivePageSourceProvider.java:129)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HivePageSourceProvider.createPageSource(HivePageSourceProvider.java:107)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.connector.classloader.ClassLoaderSafeConnectorPageSourceProvider.createPageSource(ClassLoaderSafeConnectorPageSourceProvider.java:44)
    at com.facebook.presto.split.PageSourceManager.createPageSource(PageSourceManager.java:48)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableScanOperator.createSourceIfNecessary(TableScanOperator.java:268)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableScanOperator.isFinished(TableScanOperator.java:210)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:375)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processFor(Driver.java:301)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:622)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(TaskExecutor.java:529)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$Runner.run(TaskExecutor.java:665)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:420)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:385)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetHiveRecordCursor.lambda$createParquetRecordReader$0(ParquetHiveRecordCursor.java:416)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.authentication.NoHdfsAuthentication.doAs(NoHdfsAuthentication.java:23)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HdfsEnvironment.doAs(HdfsEnvironment.java:76)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.parquet.ParquetHiveRecordCursor.createParquetRecordReader(ParquetHiveRecordCursor.java:416)
    ... 16 more
```

The parquet location is constituted by 128 parts - the data is stored on S3 and encrypted using client-side encryption with KMS. Presto uses a custom encryption-materials provider (specified using presto.s3.encryption-materials-provider) that simply returns a KMSEncryptionMaterials object initialized with my master key. I am using EMR 5.1.0 (Hive 2.1.0, Spark 2.0.1, Presto 0.152.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this surface when encryption is turned off?

There was a bugreport which surfaced against the ASF s3a client (not the EMR one), where things were breaking when the filesystem listed length != actual file length. That is: because of the encryption, the file length in a list was > the length in a read.

We couldn't repro this in our tests, and our conclusion anyway was "filesystems must not do that" (indeed, it's a fundamental requirement of the Hadoop FS spec: listed len must equal actual length). If the EMR code is getting this wrong, then it's something in their driver which the downstream code cannot be expected to handle

Comment: It works with unencrypted objects - you might be on the right track - since this is a comment I find in Presto code: 

        // NOTE: for encrypted objects, S3ObjectSummary.size() used below is NOT correct,
        // however, to get the correct size we'd need to make an additional request to get
        // user metadata, and in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: How do I turn off encryption?

Comment: Files were missing the "x-amz-unencrypted-content-length" metadata value. Presto needs this to be set to work properly with files encrypted using CSE

Comment: So the real size is listed in the header but not anything returned in the listing operation? That's trouble, deep trouble, as in "things shouldn't work like that".

Comment: Yes, in a bit of a tricky way though - once the files are written to S3 in hadoop style by EMR-FS, my script downloads the parts (implicitly unencrypting) and re-uploads them setting the header "x-amz-unencrypted-content-length" (in reality I issue an s3-copy over the same location but setting the header to save the upload time).